# WiFi Card Not showing Manjaro

Tags: wifi, macintosh, manjaro

I just installed Manjaro on my MacBook Air 2017. When i run ip link, i only see the lo device.

I should have other devices such as eth0, etc. Is it a driver issue?

I have tried the manjaro settings manager and i see BCM4360 adapter when i click show all devices.

I clicked on auto install open source driver but it only seems to be installing video drivers.

How can i get my wifi interfaces to show so i can connect to wifi?